Fermi liquid of composite fermions
I have two questions about ν=1/2 state

What happened if we add an extra electron to the composite fermion Fermi liquid state at ν=1/2?

This state is a metallic state. How the behavior of composite fermions in this state? For example, how do they move or interact with each other?


Thanks!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
